# Ito's formula for irregular functions

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let's say we have
\begin{align}
Y_t=h(t,X_t)
\end{align}
and for simplicity 
\begin{align}
dX_t=e\,dt+f\,dW_t
\end{align}
then by Ito's formula we have
\begin{align}
dY_t=\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}+e\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}f^2\frac{\partial^2h}{\partial x^2}\right)dt+f\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}dW_t
\end{align}
if $h$ is a $C^2$ function. But what happens if $h$ isn't $C^2$? What if $h$ only has some Sobolev regularity $W^{1,2}$? or maybe just a $L^p$ function, do we still have similar result?

Many Thanks!!

Comment: It's a matter of definition. If $h$ isn't $C^2$, $Y_t$ is not an Ito process.

Comment: dynamic89 : Even if Sasha's remark is correct, you can check Itô's lemma for (continuous) semimartingales, a good reference is Protter's book "Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations", or maybe George Lowther's blog (untitled "Almost Sure"). Best regards